# Change language of web interface of Microsoft Azure Account

Tags: azure

I managed to change the UI language of the Azure Portal, but the Microsoft  [Azure Account Site](https://account.windowsazure.com) did not change accordingly. I cannot find an option to change it directly there. Have I overlooked something?

Comment: You need to change your OS Language, and the Portal UI will automatic adaptation.

Comment: The UI language of the OS (i.e. my computer) from which I am accessing the portal?

Comment: Yes.  Portal UI will automatic adaptation your OS Language.

Comment: Do you use this Azure [Portal](portal.azure.com)?

Comment: Hi, does it work?

Comment: No, I am talking about https://account.windowsazure.com/. I managed to change the language in https://portal.azure.com/. Even after log-out and re-log-in the language on the accout site remains unchanged.

Comment: It seems that this link does not support multiple language. You need access your country link.

Comment: It is currently in German, but I would like to see it in English. What is the country link for English? I do not see anything like de-de or en-us as part of the link.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57990/discussion-between-walter-msft-and-david).

Comment: I suggest you could change OS language and close your browser, then open the link again.  For me, your link is English.

Comment: Hi, do you solve this issue?

Answer (score 10):

Azure Portal will automatic adaptation your OS Language. So, you could change your OS Language.

You also could change Language on Azure Portal.

[image]